# How can I export array in JS?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to export and import an array in my javascript chrome extention but it gives me **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'** error.

This is my code:

**script.js**

```
const urls = [];
for(var i = document.links.length; i --> 0;)
    if(document.links[i].hostname === location.hostname)
        urls.push(document.links[i].href);

export default urls;
```

**urls.js**

```
import urls from './script.js';

var element = document.querySelector('p');

element.textContent = urls.join('\n');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put `type="module"` in the HTML `<script>` tag calling your script.

You could also simplify your code quite a bit, for what it's worth.

```js
let urls = [];

for (const link in Document.links) {
  if (link.hostname === location.hostname) urls.push(link.href)
}

export default urls
```

Comment: What happens if you rename all the files with a `.mjs` extension?

Comment: If you want, drop a ZIP somewhere and link to it so I can try it out locally.

Comment: Change all the .js filename extensions to .mjs. Change all references to the .js files to .mjs. Add `type="module"` to all script tags. And it will work. At least, it did for me -> https://app.blackhole.run/#aoJ8Fde44T18duZUB47E1V4vo5Te7zjf9w1QdXTyv5be